# Adding an X Close

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is there any way to add an X in the corner to close this popup?
This is entered into a Plugin for WordPress called "Float Left Right Advertising Setting"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Click Me</title>
<style>
    .card {
        width: 200px;
        height: 400px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .card .img-top {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 99;
    }
    .card:hover .img-top {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card">
        <img src="https://atlashorsepowersolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/ButtonN1.png" alt=""> <a href="https://atlashorsepowersolutions.com/atlas-products/">
        <img src="https://atlashorsepowersolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/ButtonN2.png" class="img-top" alt=""> <a href="https://atlashorsepowersolutions.com/atlas-products/">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Considering you are using a plugin it depends what degree of freedom the plugin gives you.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no option in the plugin to add a close button.

Comment: Then you either need to modify the plugin with some html and javascript, or add some javascript to the theme, or use a plugin better suited for what you need. What part are you stuck at? The question as it is currently is somewhat broad.

Comment: Can I add something to my code that adds a X close to this? The div id="divFLRARight"? Site url is https://atlashorsepowersolutions.shetlerstage.com/